# Encode and Decode SNMP PDU support in Sharpsnmp

Tags: decode, encode, snmp, sharp-snmp

I like to understand if there are any APIs available in lextm sharpsnmp library  to encode SNMPv1/v2c/V3 PDU to byte array and also  API to construct a SnmpPdu (SNMP v1/v2c/v3) based on a byte array.
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

To get the raw bytes of a PDU, use [ISnmpMessage.ToBytes](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/Messaging/ISnmpMessage.cs):

```
GetRequestMessage getRequest = new(requestID, VersionCode.V1, new OctetString("public"), new Variable[] { variable });

byte[] getRequestBytes = getRequest.ToBytes();
```

To build a PDU from raw bytes, use [MessageFactory.ParseMessages](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/Messaging/MessageFactory.cs):

```
byte[] rawBytes = { 0x30, byte2, byte3, ... };

IList<ISnmpMessage> message = MessageFactory.ParseMessages(rawBytes, new UserRegistry());
```